# How to run a WCFservice automatically on windows startup

Tags: wcf, startup

I have an developed a mobile application which makes use of the WCFservices..

**DETAILS OF MY APP AND WCF-SERVICE** :
  My app has an hierarchial workflow..it has various levels of users..requests and queries are raised from users which travels up the hierarchy for approval..Here my WCFService serves the purpose of fetching,filling and saving the requests and queries from and to the database server.

**NOW HERE IS MY ACTUAL NEED :**

The WCFService must start automatically on the system boot up, so that my app starts to get notifications if there are any new requests or queries for approval.

So how do i make my service to run automaticaly when the system starts up ??? can u pls guide me through the steps ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any service posted on IIS will start automatically because on windows startup the IIs loads automatically

Answer (score 0):

You should host it using windows service. Here is one example of a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38160/WCF-Service-Library-with-Windows-Service-Hosting) that could help you.

Comment: I have hosted my service in IIS and have called it in my app also..My application's front-end is HTML and uses Javascipt/JQuery...I have used the "ajax" to call my service.. Now i need my service to run on background automatically on device start-up, so that i can receive notifications if any new request/query arises !!